# Node js is installed in my pc but during the creating of folder this error came what is this

Tags: node.js, reactjs

npx create-react-app .
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\MALIK\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\MALIK\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR!

Solve my Query. I will be very thankful to to you....

Comment: open CMD as administrator and run "npm install npm -g" then close the CMD and open it again as administrator then run "npx create-react-app project-name"

Answer (score 0):

First install npx:

```
npm i npx
```

and then run:

```
npx create-react-app project-name
```

Comment: first part worked but second part still same error

Comment: same error as mentioned in query...

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on terminal or command prompt:

`npm install npm -g`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Type "npm uninstall -g create-react-app" to uninstall the package, then install it again while making a project with "npx create-react-app my-app" and then type "y" when it asks for installation.